# File always seems to be empty

Tags: java, file-io, stream

Ok, I'm really confused by some code I wrote. It's a DataSetter (didn't know a better name for it...), and has methods to change the data in my data file (data.txt). This data has the following format: `@key=value (eg. @version=1.0)`. Now, I  tried to run this line of code:

```
new DataSetter().setValue("version", "1.1");
```

It just clears the file. That's pretty much all it does. Now, I think it clears the file because it makes a new File, which is completely empty but has the same name. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class contains methods to set specific data in the data.txt file. <br>
 * The data is rewritten every time a new value is set.
 * 
 * @author Casper van Battum
 *
 */
public class DataSetter {

    private static final File DATA_FILE = new File("resources/data.txt");
    private static final String lineFormat = "@%s=%s";

    private FileOutputStream out;
    private DataReader reader = new DataReader();
    private HashMap<String, String> dataMap = reader.getDataMap();
    private Scanner scanner;

    public DataSetter() {

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_FILE, false);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void setValue(String key, String newValue) {
        openDataFile();

        String oldLine = String.format(lineFormat, key, dataMap.get(key));
        dataMap.put(key, newValue);
        String newLine = String.format(lineFormat, key, newValue);

        try {
            replace(oldLine, newLine);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        closeDataFile();

    }

    private void replace(String oldLine, String newLine) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> tmpData = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String currentLine = scanner.nextLine();
            tmpData.add((currentLine == oldLine) ? newLine : currentLine);

        }

        out.write(new String().getBytes());

        String sep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (String string : tmpData) {
            sb.append(string + sep);

        }

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(DATA_FILE);
        String outString = sb.toString();
        writer.write(outString);
        writer.close();

    }

    private void openDataFile() {
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(DATA_FILE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void closeDataFile() {
        scanner.close();

    }

}
```

So after running the setValue() method, I just have an empty file...
Im really out of idea's on how to solve this...

Comment: *I'm really confused by some code I wrote* , then how did you write it ?

Comment: `new FileOutputStream(DATA_FILE, false)` will always clear your `DATA_FILE`.

Comment: What setvalue method. Can't see a line of code in there that writes to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are truncating your data file with the

```
new FileOutputStream(DATA_FILE, false)
```

so no nothing is written when you go to output your the elements in the `tmpData` `ArrayList` read from Scanner.

```
ArrayList<String> tmpData = new ArrayList<String>();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   String currentLine = scanner.nextLine();    // never gets called
   ...
}
```

The typical strategy for updating a text file is to create a temporary file with old file's contents ([File#renameTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29)), write the data to file, then delete the temporary file after closing any open streams to the file being read.

Comment: is this "typical strategy" a convention? Or can you also do it by, for example, add  a scanner, write the contents (including the new ones) to an array instead of the temp file and rewrite the data to the data.txt file? Or is it just better to do it the way you described?

Comment: Not a convention _per se_ but cleaner to use given that you can only read forward (unless using `RandomAccessFile`). If using a `Scanner` to write to an array, the contents could be huge, thereby having a potentially huge memory footprint :)

Comment: Ok, then I´ll do it with a temp file. It isn´t too much extra code anyways.